# What behind the scenes videos about sound design would you recommend watching on the web?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, online, sound-design, recommendations

I love watching videos about sound designers' work.  I particularly enjoy anything about or by [Ben Burtt](http://www.in.com/videos/watchvideo-ben-burtt-lecture-2-2548419.html).  What videos would you recommend?  It is always great to see other's working environments as well as hear about their motivation and techniques.  Please post any links to videos that you have enjoyed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything from http://soundworkscollection.com/

And http://designingsound.org/category/videos/

Everything from designingsound.org is great: the interviews the sound designer profiles etc

[Soundworks Collections http://designingsound.noisepages.com/files/2009/11/SoundWorksLogo.jpg](http://soundworkscollection.com/)
[image: Designing sound]
<sub>(source: [noisepages.com](http://designingsound.noisepages.com/files/2010/01/cropped-header_ds3.jpg))</sub>

Comment: My pleasure  :)

Comment: Thanks for recommend Designing Sound! I also put lots of Sound Design Videos on the "Favorites" section of the Channel on YouTube, check: http://www.youtube.com/user/designingsound

Comment: You're welcome Miguel, i REALLY like your website :)

Another really long but fun and informative video is the Audio myths workshop by Ethan Winer

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYTlN6wjcvQ

Answer (score 4):

Although not a video, I highly recommend this interview with sound designer Alan Splet, one of the great pioneers of our craft:

http://www.substation.co.nz/nzsndata/DUNEFX.html

Since it's from the early '80s you will find that much of the tech talk is quite dated; that being said, I believe that many of the most powerful tools used by sound designers are timeless.

It is a long one but worth every minute of your time.

Comment: Thanks for that! Truly fascinating article on Splet. Makes you realise how spoilt for choice we are these days in how to record and process sounds. Maybe too much choice at times for me lol 

Answer (score 3):

+1 on Soundworks Collection

Another +1 on the Lord of the Rings Extended DVD sound feature

King Kong (Seven Parts)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCpFtGCAgfI

Rob Nokes Seminar (Two Parts)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqU-oKlsGaA

Answer (score 2):

Not web videos, but here are some DVDs with sound sesign extras:

- THX 1138
- The Conversation
- Apocalypse Now
- Star Wars
- Indiana Jones
- Lord of the Rings
- Australia
- Matrix
- Artifical Intelligence
- The Bourne Identity
- Hitman
- Sixth Sense
- Panic Room
- Dark Water
- Aliens
- Master and Commander: The Far Side of the World
- Toy Story 1
- Toy Story 2
- Monsters Inc
- A Bugs Life
- Kung Fu Panda
- Wall·E
- Transformers
- Terminator
- Underlworld

Note that some of them are on the "Collectors Edition" of the film, or something like that. Also, if anyone have more to add to the list, tell us!

Comment: I'd also add the Fincher film "Seven," which has an amazing commentary track where they play JUST the SFX in some scenes, JUST the music in others, JUSt the foley in others. Riveting and supremely educational. Ren Klyce is the man! :-)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll checking it! Always love to hear from Ren Klyce :)

Answer (score 2):

interesting documentaries from the Vancouver Film Schools students:

- Game Audio: http://www.vfs.com/gallery.php?id=11&category_id=64&project_id=1023&show=all
- Foley: http://www.vfs.com/gallery.php?id=11&category_id=64&project_id=1022&show=all
- Location sound: http://www.vfs.com/gallery.php?id=11&category_id=64&project_id=1021&show=all

Comment: That makes me miss VFS... Great times

Answer (score 2):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKPGzX5kZd0

I completely forgot about this wonderful program from BBC about the early days of sound design

Answer (score 2):

This page has most dvds with sound design docs. mentioned:
http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&u=http://www.dvdsurround.ch/sounddokumentationen/
Best wishes,

Mikkel

Answer (score 1):

The DVD for "Castaway" has a commentary track that heavily features Randy Thom discussing the sound design for that movie.  I've never heard of any other dvd with a commentary track by the sound designer.  As for on the web stuff I think Designing Sound (mentioned above) has the most exhaustive selection of videos that have been posted to the web.

Answer (score 1):

In Toy Story 2 (Extended Version, 2 DVDs ) They put a fxs only Mix, no music, no voices.
Is great to hear and learn what they do. Anyone Know another DVD with this feature ?